# Elasticsearch, query array

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have the following data:

```
{"field": [{"type": "A"}, {"type": "B"}]},
{"field": [{"type": "B"}]}
```

How do you construct a query in Elasticsearch to get the *count* of all records with a specific field type value, given field is an array?

Comment: The question is not that clear. What exact result do you want to get? The title says "array length" but the questions reads like "number of documents that have a specific value for `field.value`. Could you please clarify and add a more specific example?

Comment: Updated the title. Goal is to get two things really: 1) total number of records that have a specific array item value, and 2) total length of all records where that array field is non-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html), with the following query

Query:

```
GET /index/index_type/_count
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "field.type" : "A" }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "count" : <number of docs>,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    }
}
```